# Adding an event handler when a subcontrol is instantiated

Tags: vb.net, events, user-controls

I've got a custom FlowLayoutPanel: an "AlbumFlowLayout"  which inherits from a FlowLayoutPanel and is used to hold a collection of UserControls ("AlbumItems"). Typically, this would reside on a form ("FrmMain")so that the hierarchy of items is:

```
Form ("FrmMain")
  AlbumFlowLayout ("AlbumFlowLayout1")
    AlbumItems (1 or more)
```

[Is there a way/what is the protocol] for adding a "WasClicked" handler to a created AlbumItem whenever it's created/added to the AlbumFlowLayout?

Ideally I'd like to encapsulate the handler construction code inside the AlbumFlowLayout so that it happens automatically whenever the code in FrmMain does an AlbumFlowLayout.Controls.Add of a new AlbumItem, rather than having a second line in the FrmMain add the handler before adding the control, e.g.:

```
Dim myItem As New AlbumItem

AddHandler myItem.WasClicked, AddressOf AlbumFlowLayout1.AlbumItem_WasClicked
AlbumFlowLayout1.Controls.Add(myItem)
```

Thanks!
-Pete

Comment: Container controls include a `ControlAdded` event where you could wire it up.  Not sure if that qualifies as *automatic*

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I needed. If you like, please add your response as an answer and I'll mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Plutonix had the solution. Here's what the final code looks like to use it:

```
Partial Public Class AlbumFlowLayout
  Inherits FlowLayoutPanel

  ' A FlowLayoutPanel for handling collections of AlbumItems

  Public SelectedItems As New List(Of String) 
  ' Holds IDs of currently selected items


  Private Sub AlbumFlowLayout_ControlAdded(sender As Object, e As ControlEventArgs) Handles Me.ControlAdded
    ' Wire up each user item as it's added so that it will pass its
    ' Wasclicked up to here

    Dim myAlbumItem As AlbumItem  = e.Control
    AddHandler myAlbumItem.WasClicked, AddressOf Me.AlbumItem_WasClicked
  End Sub

  ' Other methods...
  ' ...

  Public Sub AlbumItem_WasClicked(ByVal sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    ' Deselects all previously selected items. Doing this via a List to
    ' Allow for expansion item where we permit multi-selection via 
    ' Control-key or the like; currently is single-select 

    Dim myItem As AlbumItem = sender

    For Each itm As String In SelectedItems
        If itm <> myItem.Name Then
            DirectCast(Me.Controls(itm), AlbumItem).IsSelected = False
        End If
    Next

    SelectedItems.Clear()
    SelectedItems.Add(myItem.Name)
  End Sub
End Class
```